# how to calculate Numpy.prod() that doesn't fit in 32bits

Tags: python, numpy

I need to evaluate the product of a big list of integers

```
n=[3, 2, 6, 5, 1, 5, 5, 5, 3, 1, 2, 1, 6, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6 ,1 ,6, 1, 1, 6, 2, 1, 4, 6, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2, 4, 2, 5, 1, 2, 5, 4, 3, 6, 3, 1, 4, 1, 2, 5, 6, 3, 6]
np.prod(n)
>>>> -2147483648
```

However the product result should be:

```
24073471210291200000000
```

Could you please suggest a way to get around it and maintain high performance of numpy operations?

I can do the product with a for-loop but I thought it would be a slower operation in comparison to numpy.prod()

Thank you very much